# Troubleshooting HLS Streaming Setup in Nginx: 404 (Not Found) Error

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, http-live-streaming

I'm experiencing issues with setting up HLS streaming using Nginx. I have configured my Nginx server to serve HLS content, but I keep encountering a "404 (Not Found)" error when trying to access the stream.m3u8 file. Below is the configuration of my Nginx server and the site-available configuration file:

Nginx Configuration (nginx.conf):

```
`worker_processes  auto;
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

# RTMP configuration
rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
        chunk_size 4000;

        application show {
            live on;
            # Turn on HLS
            hls on;
            hls_path /nginx/hls/;
            hls_fragment 3;
            hls_playlist_length 60;
            # disable consuming the stream from nginx as rtmp
            deny play all;
        }
    }
}

http {
    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    aio on;
    directio 512;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    server {
        listen 8080;

        location / {
            # Disable cache
            add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache';

            # CORS setup
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';

            # allow CORS preflight requests
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }

            types {
                application/dash+xml mpd;
                application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
                video/mp2t ts;
            }

            root /nginx/;
        }
    }
}`
```

**`site-available`** Configuration (**`transmision.omnivision.com.sv`**):

```
server {
    root /var/www/transmision;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name transmision.omnivision.com.sv;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/transmision.omnivision.com.sv/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/transmision.omnivision.com.sv/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = transmision.omnivision.com.sv) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name transmision.omnivision.com.sv;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Despite configuring Nginx to serve HLS content, I'm unable to access the **`stream.m3u8`** file and consistently receive a "404 (Not Found)" error. Can anyone help me troubleshoot and resolve this issue? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

I configured my Nginx server following the guidelines to enable HLS streaming. I expected that upon accessing the stream.m3u8 file, it would play smoothly in the corresponding media player. However, instead of that, I received a "404 (Not Found)" error when trying to access the file.

Steps followed:

- Configured the Nginx server to enable HLS streaming using the HLS module.
- Verified that the HLS files were generated correctly in the specified directory.
- Tested playback of the stream.m3u8 file using various media players such as VLC and web players compatible with HLS.
- Checked the permissions of files and directories related to HLS streaming to ensure they were accessible by the Nginx server.
- Reviewed Nginx error logs for clues about the cause of the 404 error.

Expected outcome:
I expected that upon accessing the stream.m3u8 file, it would load successfully and start playing the video without issues.

Actual outcome:
However, upon trying to access the stream.m3u8 file, I received a "404 (Not Found)" error, which prevented video playback.

I hope this helps for sharing on Stack Overflow.